# Generate and read QR with two strings

Tags: ios, swift, qr-code

Is there any way I can add an additional string in my QR code?

I'm trying to pass two strings with keys (both are needed in my case).

So my QR code should contain authentication ID and document ID for editing a Firestore value but can't really find a good way of doing this.

```
    func generateQR(){
    let authId = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid

    if let myString = docID{
        let data = myString.data(using: .ascii, allowLossyConversion: false)

        let filter = CIFilter(name: "CIQRCodeGenerator")
        filter?.setValue(data, forKey: "inputMessage")

        let ciImage = filter?.outputImage

        let transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 10, y: 10)
        let transformImage = (ciImage?.transformed(by: transform))

        let image = UIImage(ciImage: transformImage!)

        qrView.image = image
    }
}
```

Here I'm generating my QR code and as you can see atm I just have "data" which is the document ID.

So now, somehow I need to add an additional key which should contain the "authId", is there anyway of doing this?

**Function for reading the QR message**

```
func metadataOutput(_ output: AVCaptureMetadataOutput, didOutput metadataObjects: [AVMetadataObject], from connection: AVCaptureConnection) {
    if metadataObjects != nil && metadataObjects.count != 0{
        if let object = metadataObjects[0] as? AVMetadataMachineReadableCodeObject{
            if object.type == AVMetadataObject.ObjectType.qr{

                let arr = object.stringValue!.components(separatedBy:",")
                let docId = arr.first!
                let authId = arr[1]

                let alert = UIAlertController.init(title: "QR Code", message: "Vill du använda denna QR koden?", preferredStyle: .alert)

                alert.addAction(UIAlertAction.init(title: "Ny", style: .cancel, handler: nil))

                alert.addAction(UIAlertAction.init(title: "Använd", style: .default, handler: { (nil) in

                    self.removeDiscountFromFirestore(documentId: docId, authentication: authId)
                }))

                self.present(alert, animated: true)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So how can I pass 2 strings in my QR code? Thanks in advance.

---

After Sh_Khan's input I managed to pass the data over, but they become optional and cannot be forced with "!". So I fixed this by adding

```
 let data = "\(String(describing: docID!)),\(authId!)".data(using: .ascii, allowLossyConversion: false)
```

Where I generate the QR code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to concatenate them with say a `,`

```
 let data = "\(docId),\(authId)".data(using: .ascii, allowLossyConversion: false)
```

And when you read the qr code separate them

```
 let arr = object.stringValue!.components(separatedBy:",")  
 let docId = arr.first!
 let authId = arr[1]
```

Comment: That seems to work fine.

But the problem is that the strings become optional and I cannot unforce it using "!" cuz it will remain the same. Any idea?

Comment: ok change this line `let arr = object.stringValue!.components(separatedBy:",")  `

Comment: Change it to what? It's the exact same, isn't it?

Comment: it's `.stringValue!` instead of `.stringValue`

Comment: the string encoding should be `isoLatin1` From the docs "Generates an output image representing the input data according to the ISO/IEC 18004:2006 standard. The width and height of each module (square dot) of the code in the output image is one point. **To create a QR code from a string or URL, convert it to an NSData object using the NSISOLatin1StringEncoding string encoding.**"